# Expressing a vector as a linear combination in a parallellogram

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

A parallellogram $ABCD$ is given, where $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $F$ is a point on $AD$ so that $|FD| = 3|AF|$. $G$ is the point where $BF$ and $AE$ intersects.

Express the vector $AG$ in terms of vectors $AB$ and $AD$.

My solution to the problem is the following: Impose an *affine transformation* so that $ABCD$ becomes a unit square with point $A$ residing on origo. Then $BF$ is on the line $y = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}x$ and $AE$ on $y = \frac{1}{2}x$. The lines' intersection gives me the required coefficients to express $AG$ in terms of $AB$ and $AD$.

My question is how would you solve this problem without the affine transformation? The reason I'm asking is because this problem was given at an early stage of the course before affine transformations was introduced. So I want to know if there is a simpler or "more intuitive" way to solve it which I haven't learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the triangles AFG and BEG are similar. since AF is a quarter of AD, and BE is one half of BC(which is equal to AD) we can say that $\dfrac{AG}{EG} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ so it is obvious that $\dfrac{AG}{AE} = \dfrac{1}{3}$

Know we know that AE is just the sum of the vectors: $AB + BE = AB + \dfrac{AD}{2}$

On the other hand we know that AG is just one third of AE. So:

$AG = \dfrac{AB + \dfrac{AD}{2}}{3}$

Comment: How do you know that the triangles are similar?

Comment: Because their sides are parallel. And they have the same vertex G.

Comment: Thus they have three equal angles.

Answer (score 3):

Sure: My standard way of teaching this material is to set $\overrightarrow{AB}=\vec x$ and $\overrightarrow{AD} = \vec y$ and write everything appropriate in terms of those vectors. In particular, $\overrightarrow{AE} = \vec x + \frac12\vec y$ and $\overrightarrow{AF} = \frac14\vec y$. We want to find $t$ so that $\vec x+t(\frac14 y-\vec x)$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec x+\frac12\vec y$. 
Setting $$\vec x+t(\tfrac14 y-\vec x)=c(\vec x+\tfrac12\vec y)$$
and using linear independence of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, it is easy to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive my lack of vector symbols below.

---

$AE = AB+\dfrac12AD$

$BF = -AB+\dfrac14AD$

---

Let $AG = hAB+kAD$.

Since $AG // AE$, we have $h=2k$.

Since $BG // BF$, we have $-(h-1)=4k$.

---

Solving for $h$ and $k$ gives $h=\dfrac13$ and $k = \dfrac16$, so:

$$AG=\dfrac13AB+\dfrac16AD$$

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward once you show that $\overrightarrow{AG} = \frac13 \overrightarrow{AE}$. Then we have $$\overrightarrow{AG} = \frac13(\frac12\overrightarrow{AB} + \frac12\overrightarrow{AC}) = \frac16 \overrightarrow{AB} + \frac16 \overrightarrow{AC} = \frac16 \overrightarrow{AB} + \frac16 (\overrightarrow{AB} + \frac16 \overrightarrow{AD}) = \frac13 \overrightarrow{AB} + \frac16 \overrightarrow{AD}.$$

We can get here in a few ways, including but not limited to:

- By similar triangles: if you choose $H$ on $AD$ such that $BH \parallel EF'$, then $\triangle AFG \sim \triangle AHE$. We can get the coefficient of similarity from the observation that $$AH = AF + FH = AF + BE = \frac14 AD + \frac12 AC = \frac34 AD,$$ while $AF = \frac14 AD$, so $\triangle AFG = \frac13 \triangle AHE$, and $AG = \frac13 AE$.
- By the area method. The ratio $AG : GE$ is the ratio $S_{ABF} : S_{BEF}$. Since 
  \begin{align}
  S_{ABF} &= \frac14 S_{ABD} = \frac18 S_{ABCD} \\
  S_{BEF} &= \frac12 S_{BCF} = \frac12 S_{BCA} = \frac14 S_{BCDA}\end{align}
  we get $AG : GE = \frac18 : \frac14 = 1 : 2$.
- It is evident from the diagram below once we draw some more lines parallel to $BF$:

[image: parallelogram]

The similar triangles method (or some equivalent vector computation) is probably what you were intended to use, but I prefer the area approach for being systematic. We have $E$ in terms of $B$ and $C$, $F$ in terms of $A$ and $D$, and $G$ in terms of $BF$ and $AE$, so we just undo these constructions until we have expressed the desired ratio $AG : GE$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.